# Changing output path of XAML files in VIsual Studio 2015 Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a VCXProj file for a Universal Windows app that compiles some xaml files

```
<Page Include="..\View\ViewModel.xaml" />
```

One result of this is the xaml file is deployed as part of the package as a resource: ms-appx:///AppNamespace/ViewModel.xaml

If the file path was instead "View\ViewModel.xaml" then the resource path would also be "AppNamespace/View/ViewModel.xaml"

Unfortunately, since it is in the parent directory, it gets flattened and goes in the root.  I want a way to specify the output path, rather than let the MSBuild system preserve it, something like

```
<Page Include="..\View\ViewModel.xaml">
    <TargetPath>View\MyViewModel.xaml</TargetPath>
</Page>
```

But I cannot for the life of me find a way to do this. Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is by design, I couldn't find an option in VS tool that can specify the output path of a xaml file.

By default if you create a View folder in your project from VS, and create a new Page in this View folder, the VS compiler will automatically extract this XAML file out of the View folder and put it in the root folder of your project folder. And even you created one folder in the project from VS, this folder will not be created actually in your project physical folder.

For example, I created a folder named "Test" from VS, and I copied an image into this folder. The path of this image is actually like this:`<Image Include="C:\Users\(pc-account)\Pictures\1.jpeg" />`, and you will not find the "Test" folder in the physical path of this project. Now if we create a folder also named "Test" in the physical path, not only from VS, and copy another image into this folder, open this project from you VS, right click the "Test" folder, by adding existing item to select the second image into this "Test" folder, then you can see from VS：

[image]

And in the Appx folder of your project it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the first image which is added to the project from VS is extracted from the Test folder to the root folder, and the second image which is manfully added to the project is still in the Test folder.

You can see the path of this two images in the VCXProj file like this:

[image]

I'm afraid there is no options in VS tool that can automatically do this work, we can only

1. manually create a folder with the same name as one created from VS tool.
2. copy the .xaml, .xaml.cpp, and .xaml.h file into this manually-created folder.
3. add existing item from vs to this folder.

[image]

4. debug your project then you can see this View2 folder in the Debug folder.

[image]

5. in the meanwhile, in your VCXProj file you can see this xaml page's path:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detail. I played with it a lot and dug through some of the props and schemas and came up with something that seems to do what I want, actually. It does require a manual step - the <Link> nodes. For example

<Page Include="C:\foo.xaml">
    <Link>View\foo.xaml</Link>
</Page>

Only useful for the page node though